# OBSOLETE - Stack Viewer - App for navigate in Stack Overflow and more

Tags: app, obsolete, android

> ## Obsolete: Links are dead; no source code.

This is a native android app for navigate in Stack Overflow.
You can see answers, questions, best users by reputation, search by text and tags among other things.
It's open source.

- <del>[Code in Github.](https://github.com/maxwellnewage/stackoverflow-viewer)</del>  (Dead link)
- <del>[The App in Google Play.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxwell.stackviewer)</del>  (Dead link)